# Call ./.../bin/spark-submit pythonfile.py in eclipse (Pydev) console when running program

Tags: eclipse, pydev, pyspark

**Current situation which works fine:**

- I'm currently programming my Pyspark files in eclipse with the Pydev plugin
- I manually execute these files in the ubuntu shell with the following command:

  ./.../bin/spark-submit pythonfile.py

**Desired situation:**

When I press the "run" button in eclipse, eclipse will call the command mentioned above and show the console output in the eclipse console.

Is this possible and if yes, could someone give me a clue on how to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend an external launch.

From the `Run` menu, choose `External Tools | External Tools Configurations...` and then create a launch configuration specifying the command you want to run.

You can generalize the command a little by using `Variables` For example:

- Location: `${workspace_loc:/myprojectname}/../bin/spark-submit`
- Working Directory: `${workspace_loc:/myprojectname}`
- Arguments: `${workspace_loc:/myprojectname/myscript.py}`

This is what a screenshot of the configuration looks like.

[image: spark launch config]

Additionally, in the Common tab you have a control over whether the output is captured in a console (the default) and/or redirected to a file. In this example screenshot, the output comes to a console and is written to a file back in my project:

- Output file: `${workspace_loc:/myprojectname/build_output}`

[image: console settings]

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks for putting so much effort in this explanation!